# php get the student id who have "in" and "out"

Tags: php

I have a code to count student id who has "in" and "out" all I want is to get the student id who have "in" and "out",if the student have only "in" I want to execute this code

> INSERT INTO `log` ( `stud_id`, `date_log`, `time_log`, `ampm`, `status_log`, `status`) VALUES
>   ('student id who has "in" only', 'currentdate', 'current time', 'PM', 'out', 1),

This is my existing code.

```js
$total=mysql_query("SELECT count(stud_id) as mycount, stud_id, date_log FROM `log` 
WHERE date_log >= CURRENT_DATE() and ampm='pm'  GROUP BY stud_id");
$d=mysql_fetch_assoc($mycount);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL doesn't support WHERE statements in INSERTs. Instead you could pull the information from the database doing a SELECT query and then do an IF statement to do your inserts. As so:

```
            $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM log WHERE date_log >= CURRENT_DATE() and ampm='pm'  GROUP BY stud_id");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) { 
if ($row['status_log'] == "in") {
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO log ( stud_id, date_log, time_log, ampm, status_log, status) VALUES ('".$row['stud_id'].", 'currentdate', 'current time', 'PM', 'out', 1)");
}}
```

**NOTE** I wrote this with assumptions to how your database is filled out. I HIGHLY doubt it will be a copy and paste code.

Source of INSERT information:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

EDIT: Updated because of syntax error